# How to trigger the pan gesture in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, gesture

For pinch I could hold down the option/alt key , click and move the mouse. What for pan?
I googled but can not find the answer.Thanks.

Comment: When you say "pan", don't you mean just dragging around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

panning is just dragging, right? click in the simulator and move your mouse while holding it down.
Or do you want to pan with two touches at once. Hold the Shift key pressed, than you can move both touch points at once.

Comment: It seems even if i did not hold the shift key , i could still pan with two fingers.

Comment: Yes, but if you also have UILongPressGestureRecognizer, the difference between a long-press-and-drag and a pan in the simulator with a trackpad/mouse can be negligible

Answer (score 20):

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click & Drag.

You can also use this to adjust where you're pinching.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I don't have a mouse and accepted answer did not work for me

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

For pan gesture you would drag the view around, click on the view, and while still clicking drag the mouse around